# Where are Additional CSS files stored

Tags: customization, themes, css

[image: Wordpress Additional CSS]

This image shows the Additional CSS feature in Wordpress. I'm trying to find the file that stores the additional CSS, but can't seem to find it anywhere - I've searched almost every folder in wp-content!

Does anyone know how Additional CSS for the theme is stored and, if it is in a file, where this file is located!

Comment: The best idea is keep it in separate file on the server. Than you can edite and make any changes quickly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's stored in the database, within the `wp_posts` table, under the `custom_css` post type, where the post name is the theme slug. There you also have the related `customize_changeset` and `revision` post types.

The *custom css post ID* is also stored in the `wp_options` table under each *theme mods*, e.g. `theme_mods_twentysixteen` for *Twenty Sixteen*.

It's informative to check out how the custom CSS fetched from the database with:

- [`wp_get_custom_css()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_custom_css/) that uses [`wp_get_custom_css_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_custom_css_post/)

and displayed through the `wp_head` action with:

- [`wp_custom_css_cb()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_custom_css_cb/)

Comment: If it's stored in the database does that mean that it will not be removed if/when I update my theme?

Comment: updating the current theme, shouldn't remove the stored CSS.

Comment: This allowed me to copy the customizations from the parent theme to the child theme so I did not need to re-create the home page.

Answer (score 13):

type this into the sql query if your new like me, and it should come up.

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'custom_css'