# Why is the "Additional CSS" section missing in my theme Customizer?

Tags: css, theme-customizer, wp-config

Since upgrading to WordPress 5.7.1, the "Additional CSS" option seems to be missing in Customizer at Appearance -> Customize on various WordPress websites I look after with various different themes including Astra and GeneratePress.

I have updated the plugins and themes to the latest versions but this has not helped.

I have tried temporarily changing to a default theme (Twenty Twenty-One) but this does not help either.

I realise I can add custom CSS via a plugin and possibly via a child theme but what happened to this option?

Update: This option appears as expected in a fresh install of WordPress 5.7.1 with the default Twenty Twenty-One theme.

Comment: Most probably a plugin conflict. Disable all your plugin and reactivate them one by one to test. If you have jetpack plugin activated, I suggest you start disabling that first.

Comment: That's a good suggestion thanks. I tried temporarily disabling all plugins on one website but it didn't help. I look after 6 x WordPress websites that are all very diverse in terms of themes and plugins so it seems most likely to me that this was due to the WordPress update. Does anyone still have this option available on WordPress 5.7?

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be any solution to this question in the meantime, the work around I am using for now is editing the database via phpMyAdmin. For details see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258230/64657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself after a year and a half.

I'm not sure how this value was changed but changing:

```
define('DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', true);
```

in `wp-config.php` back to:

```
define('DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', false);
```

has fixed the problem.